# Why does the whole native app freeze, when I overload the webview component?

Tags: ios, react-native

So I have an app that looks like this

`<WebView
        injectedJavaScript={while(true){}}
        javaScriptEnabled
      />`

Why does the whole app freeze in this case? WebView should run its javascript in a separate thread, why is the main (ui) thread blocked?

Comment: The same thing happens when [doing this on android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20684004/7064175)

Comment: good point! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139509/can-i-run-a-uiwebview-in-a-seperate-thread seems that everything from the UIWebView (including javascript) is done on the main thread....